# How to get the ID of a clicked element, when it or its children are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**UPDATED**

I think I may have inadvertently made the question confusing. This is an update that is more specific with updated code based on comments and answer I have been given so far. Thank you to everyone that has taken the time to comment and answer.

How can I get the ID of a `<div>` with the class of `.button` when I have a click listener for `.button`. If `.button` or any of its children are clicked, it should return the ID for that particular `div` with the class of `.button`.

This is what I have so far: [New JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/L65sma8x/)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="b1" class="button">
    <h2>Button 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="b2" class="button">
    <h2>Button 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="b3" class="button">
    <h2>Button 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var selected = "";

$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  selected = e.target.id;

  $('.button').css('backgroundColor', '#becde5');
  $('#' + selected).css('backgroundColor', '#3b71c6');

  $('#selected').html(selected);
});
```

This is almost correct but does not propagate, if I click on a `<h2>` the function does not work. However if I click on the `.button` div itself it works.

**Initial Question**

I am trying to create a general function that can identify what child was selected from its parents click listener. The child may have its own children that would all be considered part of the same element so that if any of these children where selected they should also elicit the same response from the click listener.

This is an example of what I have working so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/wrzn09r0/)

HTML consisting of three buttons that all have one child `<h2>` tag and share the `<div class="row">` as their parent.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="b1 button">
    <h2 class="b1">Button 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="b2 button">
    <h2 class="b2">Button 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="b3 button">
    <h2 class="b3">Button 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery that listens for a click on `<div class="row">`. It retrieves the first class name of the clicked element and stores it in a variable. The elicited response in this case is a change of the CSS style `background-color` though this is arbitrary and would change depending on the use of the function.

```
var selected = "";

$('.row').on('click', function(e) {
  selected = e.target.className.split(" ")[0];

  $('.b1, .b2, .b3').css('backgroundColor', '#becde5');
  $("." + selected).css('backgroundColor', '#3b71c6');

  $('#selected').html(selected);
});
```

The fact that I am adding a lot of classes to elements purely to identify them on a click seems like it would not scale very well and is generally a bad approach. This method also means that I would always have to put the class name that identifies what element was selected at the beginning of its HTML `class` attribute. This could potentially clash with other functions using the same method.

Is there a better way to identify what child element was selected from its parents click listener, where a child may have other children that also require the same response from the listener?

Comment: Why not bind the click handler to `".row > div.button"`? You can still have one on `".row"` if you need to clear them when clicking outside the button, though you'll need to do `event.stopPropagation()` in side the `.button` handler.

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for this?

Comment: *"Is there a better way to identify what child element was selected from its parents click listener, where a child may have other children that also require the same response from the listener?"* How do you plan to identify those elements? You must have **some** way. For instance, in your example above, **all** elements within the `.row` have one of those three classes, so you could just use `$(this).find("*")` to get them all. But it seems unlikely to be what you want... If you tell us what your rule is, we can help you figure out how to apply it with the various traversal functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the response. If I understand you correctly, the rule is to not need to use a repeating class name on each child. If the parent button could for example have an ID and then any child under this parent could elicit the same response that is appropriate to that button. I am not sure if this is called propagation? The fact that any child would propagate to then fire the listener of that particular button?

Comment: @squint Hello, thanks for comment. So if I bind the click handler to `".row > div.button"` would this mean that, for example, if someone clicked the `<h2>` of the button with class `b2` that it could return the class name `b2` without actually  having to mark up the `<h2>` tag itself with the class name `b2`? Would this also be true for any number of `b2`'s children?

Comment: @Todd: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I am sorry, this is probably because I am misusing terms out of a lack of understanding. I understand what you mean "How do you plan to identify those elements?" I see that @squint has suggested that I bind the click listener to `".row > div.button"` essentially making each button the respective parent in this context as opposed to my first attempt of binding it to `.row`. I do not fully understand it yet but it seems I could use DOM propagation in such a way that any child of `.button` would fire the listener and return that particular buttons ID. Thanks both for the help.

Comment: I don't get your update... This removes all the complexity of the question. Why to you stick on using the `e.target` when what you really want is `$(this)`? In [this updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/xc9hjhs3/) I added some other childs inside the `.button` element. And the right id is cached with `$(this)` even if the target is a child of it.

Comment: This is what I wanted. I think I initially worded it poorly making it seem much more complex than it really was. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's done... Now you know `e.target` really defines... It can be usefull in another situation. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** based on the edited question:

I think that what you really want is the `id` of the element that triggered the event.
But by using `e.target` you have the target element... which is not necessarily the element that triggered the event.

See in [this updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/xc9hjhs3/).

So simply use `$(this)` as the selector to retrieve the id... Using `.attr("id")`.

;)

**Answer to the initial question**:
To determine what can be "selected", I used a "clickable" class.

To avoid using `id` or `class` as an identifier to determine what has been clicked,
a `data` attribute can be usefull.

I used `data-id`... But you can use whatever you want, like: `data-selected` or `data-target`, and assign whatever value to it.

In the below code, I made two exactly identical rows, except their `data-id` value.

```js
var selected = "";

$('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // To prevent bubbling.

    // Reset all bg colors
    $('.button').css('backgroundColor', 'initial');
    $('.row').css('backgroundColor', 'initial');

    // Find exactly what was clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("row")) {
        var row = $(this).data("id");
        selected = row + " (whole)";
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass("button")) {
        // Find in which row
        var row = $(this).closest(".row").data("id");
        var btn = $(this).data("id");
        selected = btn + " in " + row;
    }

    // Pale all buttons
    $('.button').css('backgroundColor', '#becde5');
    // Change bg color of the selected element
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#3b71c6');

    $('#selected').html(selected);
});
```

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

.button {
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #6fa1f2;
    text-align: center;
}

#selected {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Selected : <span id="selected">no selection</span></span><br>
<div class="row clickable" data-id="row1">
    <div class="button clickable" data-id="btn1">
        <h2>Button 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="button clickable" data-id="btn2">
        <h2>Button 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="button clickable" data-id="btn3">
        <h2>Button 3</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row clickable" data-id="row2">
    <div class="button clickable" data-id="btn1">
        <h2>Button 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="button clickable" data-id="btn2">
        <h2>Button 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="button clickable" data-id="btn3">
        <h2>Button 3</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Louys and your answer to the initial question is not wasted as I was not aware of `data` attributes before and I am sure this example of their use will help me and others.

Comment: Haha sorry if that seemed cheeky, I thought there was a badge you get for editing an answer you have accepted, seeing as yours is the first I've accepted. It appears there isn't...

Comment: There is one when you edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0) --> Explainer. ;) [Badges definitions are here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Answer (score 0):

no need to id the subject, since it was the one clicked, i.e. `e.target` which with jQuery you cant select like `$(e.target)` without any trouble

then you need `.closest('.button')` to search up to the parent `.button` (if any)

```js
$('.row').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.row > .button').css('backgroundColor', '#becde5');
  $(e.target).closest('.button').css('backgroundColor', '#3b71c6');

  console.log($(e.target).html());
});
```

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="button">
    <h2>Button 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <h2>Button 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <h2>Button 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid giving an identifier (classes, IDs, etc) you'd need to do some manual checking for tag type to see what you clicked on (so basically, an identifier as well)

Here's an example, and not very memory efficient method
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/whtey1jf/6/)

```
$('.row, .row  *').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()    

  $('.button').removeClass('active')
  $('.button').css('backgroundColor', '#becde5');

  $(this).toggleClass('active')

  $('#selected').html(e.target.tagName + ': ' + e.target.className);
});
```

If you bind a click to div.row and clicked the h2 tag inside the button, and want to manipulate the h2 tag, you could check its tagName- but that less scalable than your OP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, from looking at the JSFiddle this gets the specific element clicked. What I meant by "function that can identify what child was selected from its parents click listener" was that the parent click listener placed on `<div class="row">` could identify if either `.b1`, `.b2` or `.b3` was clicked. Thank you though for the time spent on this answer and it looks quite useful for particular use cases.